# How to set the user to whom we need to send approval request.

Tags: trigger, approval-process

I have a trigger from where I need to submit a record for approval. With that I also want to set to how it should send for approval. Is this possible to do from trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely submit a record for approval from a trigger. Have a look at the following example for an Opportunity Approval Process:

```
trigger OpportunitySubmitForApproval on Opportunity (after update) {

    for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {

        if (Trigger.old[i].Probability < 30 && Trigger.new[i].Probability >= 30) {

            // create the new approval request to submit
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
            req.setObjectId(Trigger.new[i].Id);
            // submit the approval request for processing
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
            // display if the reqeust was successful
            System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());

        }

    }

}
```

Source: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/04/automating-salesforce-approval-processes-with-apex-triggers/

If you want to dynamically set the user who approves the process, you can do the following:

1. Set the approval process up to use the Approver field of the Record Owner.
2. Now, before you submit the Approval Request in your trigger, update the Approver field of the Record Owner so that the Approval Request is routed correctly.